# eslint in WebStorm line breaks keep changing back to LF

Tags: newline, webstorm, eslint

The code I'm working on has `LF` line breaks.  I use WebStorm on Windows and I have set up `File > Settings > Editor > Code Style > Line separator  (new files)` to `Windows (\r\n)`.

In my `.eslintrc.js` file I have the rule below:

```
'linebreak-style': [
  'error',
  'windows'
],
```

I also choose the root of the project in the project explorer and then choose `File > Line separators > Windows - CRLF(\r\n)`.

But, every time I change something in the code and save, the file jumps back to `LF` (I can see that in the bottom right corner of the WebStorm) and that generates lots of errors from eslint. I have to manually change the file line breaks back to `CRLF` every time I edit and save my code.

I have also `--fix` switch in my eslint command and I expect it to fix this error automatically, but it doesn't.

What can I have missed here? Any clues?

Comment: do you have .editorconfig files anywhere in your project? It may affect EOL. Try disabling editorconfig support in File | Settings | Editor | Code Style by unchecking 'Enable Editorconfig support' checkbox - does it make any difference?

Comment: Oh, that was it! Thank you lena! There is a .editorconfig file in the project. I just changed the "end_of_line = lf" to "end_of_line=crlf" and now it works with no troubles. :)